# Downloading Instagram Photos Like RSS Feed

Tags: windows, rss, instagram, screensaver

Trying to make a desktop slideshow screensaver. Instead of the same pictures time and time again I thought it would be cool to pull from an Instagram feed.

RSS feeds can be used to get live data from sites like Facebook, twitter, etc. I was wondering if there is a way to have a similar effect for downloading Instagram photos.

What I need:

- Program that updates once a day
- Searches a specific Instagram account, or multiple
- Downloads the latest 10 photos for example
- Removes old photos (so the folder doesn't get oversized)

That way Windows can pull the photos from that folder to use for a slideshow.

Anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this? Or how to go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Outdated, Unfortunately Instagram changed it's settings and now this no longer works**

---

Turns out it's far easier than that. A program called

[Screenstagram](https://www.google.com/amp/lifehacker.com/5993914/screenstagram-livens-up-your-screensaver-with-instagram-photos/amp)

Has this capability and more